# Liferay Unsychnonized message listener, Send message to page after complete backend operation

Tags: liferay, long-polling, message-listener

I have implemented **`Liferay asynchronous MessageListener`**
to do one task, which takes about 20 minutes, that is the  reason why I am using message listener.

But my requirement that, after complete back-end process **I have to show success message to user** like "Your data successfully loaded...". I don't want to use **Ajax Polling**

Please suggest me:

**How can I do this stuffs in liferay? Is there any long polling procedure in liferay?**

Ps: I am using **liferay 6.1.2-ce-ga3**

As a reference, I used this doc: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/lp-6-1-dgen09-using-message-bus-0

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Ajax, I'd recommend to implement some "current status". Whenever a portlet is displayed it can display if the operation is currently still executing or if it has completed. How do you figure this out? Well, that's part of your backend implementation, not the portlet level, as that's UI.

With this, you could also extend the UI for your status list to be updated through Ajax, which incidently is not too hard, once you're ready to go for Ajax.

On the frontend, you don't want long polling HTTP requests open through the application server - if you're looking for this.

There's also a mechanism that Liferay's chat portlet and the notification portlet use, called poller. However, this is also Ajax, so I don't know if that qualifies for your requirements. Check [this forum post](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4297443), note, it's quite old and the mentioned bug seems to be fixed. I don't know if the Developer Guide has a chapter on it as well, but with that name I'm confident that you can find more information